# More options for `This question belongs on another site`

Tags: feature-request

When making a vote to close a question there's the option to vote `This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network`.

Currently this feature only allows the user to declare the question to be moved to meta.StackExchange. I think other SE-sites such as `infosec.SE`, `physics.SE`, `politics.SE` and `biology.SE` should also be possile choices.

Answer (score 1):

Moderators can migrate anywhere, so it makes sense to look at the stats. Of course you could say this is part of the problem, as well ;-)

While your choices are sensible, the only site in your list where actually migrated anything in the past 90 days is physics.SE, and the question was rejected.

On the other hand, there are 2 more graduated sites where we migrated questions: chemistry.SE and cooking.SE.

The other sites where we migrated are beta and they should be excluded from any migration list until they graduate: aviation, economics, history, biblical hermeneutics, and law.

Comment: I grant that chemistry.SE and cooking.SE would also be good to have in the list. I however don't see a reason not to have any choices for migration for normal close votes.

Comment: @Christian the historical reason is that there's basically no volume going out. Let's see what the community says. I see no problem turning more choices on if people find them useful.

Comment: Minor note: [Aviation is no longer in beta](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2844/congratulations-aviation-is-graduating)

Comment: Didn't there used to be a (rather small) limit on the number of destination sites that can be on the list?  Is that no longer true?